# Show side-nav on page load - Jquery / HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I make my side nav show on the page loading? I still want to be able to toggle though.

```js
//Toggle On/Off
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 325px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 325px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -325px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #286090;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 325px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -325px;
}


/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 325px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 325px;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 325px;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">☰</a>
          </div><br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where on your page is this script? Also I don't see an element with the id `wrapper`.

Comment: bottom of my body

Comment: share css please

Comment: Luke, the answer you selected is unable to re-toggle once closed, also, you are adding a click handler inside another click, that can lead to potential conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by adding `.click()`

```js
//Toggle On/Off
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
}).click(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< add .click() here
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 325px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 325px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -325px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #286090;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 325px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -325px;
}


/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 325px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 325px;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 325px;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">☰</a>
          </div><br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to use your code... but this should help focus. The first thing you can do is 'trigger' a click event to toggle the class right away. The other thing you could do is put the CSS class 'menu-open' on the body by default - and toggle from there. You could also add that class with JS.

> How can I make my side nav show on the page loading? I still want to
>   be able to toggle though.

```js
// using some jQuery
var $body = $('body');
var $menuToggle = $('[rel="menu-toggle"]');

$menuToggle.on('click', function() {
  $body.toggleClass('menu-open');
}).trigger('click'); 
// trigger a click to start (on load or whatever)

// or not as a chained method like this:
// $menuToggle.trigger('click');
```

```css
.sidebar {
  background: gray;
  padding: 1rem;
}

body.menu-open .sidebar {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='menu-toggle' rel='menu-toggle'>☰</button>

<aside class='sidebar'>sidebar</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make my side nav show on the page loading? I still want to be able to toggle though.

- First, I'd suggest you take the toggle button out of that html structure, so it doesn't hide with the sidebar, therefore preventing to re-toggling it after closed.
- Once toggle is out and always present, position it to your desire, in this case it is located at the right due to the `.pull-right` class.
- Toggle sidebar on `document.ready()` to appear open when document finished loading.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //toggle sidebar on document ready
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});

//Toggle On/Off
$("#menu-toggle").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 325px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 325px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -325px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #286090;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 325px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -325px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 325px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 325px;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 325px;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">☰</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
 }

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 325px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 325px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -325px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #286090;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 325px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -325px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 325px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 325px;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 325px;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the Edit button below your question to add information to it, and remove this, as it is not an answer.